# Describe all continuous functions on Sorgenfrey line

Tags: general-topology

I have to describe all continuous functions on the Sorgenfrey line i.e. $ f:(\mathbb{R},\tau_\rightarrow)\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ where $\tau_\rightarrow$ is Sorgenfrey line.

How should I describe it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at local bases, we can give an $\varepsilon, \delta$ reformulation:

$$\forall x \in \Bbb R: \forall \varepsilon >0 : \exists \delta >0: \forall y \in \Bbb R: (x < y < x+\delta) \to (|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon)$$

A function that is continuous in this context, but not usually (between regular reals) is a function like $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
                         0 & x < 0 \\ 
                         1 & x \ge 0\\
\end{cases}$$

So functions that are "continuous from the right": if $x_n \downarrow x$ the $\lim_n f(x_n)=f(x)$, etc.